# How can I change value in choice column in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps-modeldriven

I need to change value of choices in choice type column in CRM. There is one field name and other is value. I am able to change the name as we know but not the value of it

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the modern PowerApps maker portal still has some limitations, it does not contain all the functionalities for parity as in our classic D365 editors. You are hitting one of those limitations.

Pls switch to classic version from the maker portal or navigate to the classic by clicking the top gear icon in Model driven app, then click the "Advanced settings".

Under Settings - Solutions - Entity - Field, you can edit the existing options, both the text and value. This will unblock you for time being.

[image]

[Read more](https://medium.com/@lsg.chronicles/first-step-overview-of-options-set-field-in-dynamics-365-359767c717cb)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a virtual entity connector in your DataVerse to your CRM data, you can change all your choices from there as well.

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice we should create different choice which is re-usable at any
places. One can create the choice by clicking on `New` select `More` and then `Choices`. Once created the choice, can able to add different choice name along with their default value. if needed to change the value we can edit those. please check below image[image]